# Rails - pass a second value based on form input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, parameters, simple-form

I think what I am trying to do is simple in theory but I'm having a hard time putting it into words to search for a solution.

on my Contest form I have a collection select-

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :matchup_id, 'Select Matchset' %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:matchset_id, Matchset.where("starttime > ?", Time.now), :id, :name, { :prompt => true } ) %>
```

For whichever matchset they choose here, I want to pass that Matchset's starttime to the field also called starttime on this Contest model.

Editing for clarification: I want to pass a second value from the Matchset model to the Contest model based on the user's selection in the collection select. So if the user selects matchset 1 in the collection select, I want to pass 1 as the matchset_id to Contest but I also want to take the starttime from matchset 1 and pass that as the starttime for the Contest record I'm creating as well. Any tips for a newbie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to assign the `starttime` value to a `Contest` in the controller. In the action this view is calling, after you have assigned the selected `matchset` to the `contest`, you can access the `starttime` by calling:

```
@contest.matchset.starttime
```

It will be a little different if the contest `has_many matchsets` but it's the same idea.

Comment: This is exactly what I just tried and it worked. Came here to answer my question but you already did. Good to know I can assign records values like this. Thanks.